# Prepared statement puts \ before '

Tags: php, prepared-statement

Im using prepared statements to descramble BBcode but for some reason it puts \ before ' when posting. I dont know what causes it, but Im sure it happens when i change the BBcode to html to be put in the database, the code looks like this:

```
$text = $membership->remove_HTML($text);


    //convert line breaks to <br /> tags.
      $text = nl2br($text);

      //cleans up by removing white space.
      $text = trim($text);

      //now lets replace things BASIC EDITOR
      $text = preg_replace("/\[b\](.*)\[\/b\]/", "<strong>\\1</strong>", $text);
      $text = preg_replace("/\[i\](.*)\[\/i\]/", "<em>\\1</em>", $text);
      $text = preg_replace("/\[u\](.*)\[\/u\]/", "<span style='text-decoration:underline;'>\\1</span>", $text);
      $text = preg_replace("/\[s\](.*)\[\/s\]/", "<del>\\1</del>", $text);

      $text = preg_replace("/\[url\](.*)\[\/url\]/", "<a target='_blank' href='\\1'>\\1</a>", $text);
      $text = preg_replace("/\[url=(.*)\](.*)\[\/url\]/", "<a target='_blank' rel='\\1' href='\\1'>\\2</a>", $text);

      //now lets replace MORE things EXPANDED EDITOR
      $text = preg_replace("/\[img\](.*)\[\/img\]/", "<img>\\1</img>", $text);
      $text = str_ireplace("[hr]","<hr>", $text);
      $text = preg_replace("/\[justify\](.*)\[\/justify\]/", "<p style='text-align:justify;'>\\1</p>", $text);
      $text = preg_replace("/\[center\](.*)\[\/center\]/", "<p style='text-align:center;'>\\1</p>", $text);
      $text = preg_replace("/\[left\](.*)\[\/left\]/", "<p style='text-align:left;'>\\1</p>", $text);
      $text = preg_replace("/\[right\](.*)\[\/right\]/", "<p style='text-align:right;'>\\1</p>", $text);
      $text = preg_replace("/\[h1\](.*)\[\/h1\]/", "<h4>\\1</h4>", $text);
      $text = preg_replace("/\[h2\](.*)\[\/h2\]/", "<h5>\\1</h5>", $text);
      $text = preg_replace("/\[h3\](.*)\[\/h3\]/", "<h6>\\1</h6>", $text);

      $updatenews = $mysql->add_news($_SESSION['user'][0], $headline, $text, $time);
```

Comment: AAAGGHHH MY EYES!! WHAT IS THIS PARSING!? WHAT DOES IT MEAN!?

Comment: Just as a point of interest, you may wish to check out the BBCode functions. http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest thing to check is making sure PHP's Magic Quotes are [disabled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

If you don't want to get right into mucking around with your PHP configuration, then check to see if the slashes are present before you roll `$text` through that series of `preg_replaces()`.

Comment: thank you! I modified my ini file and now everything works fine.